# Error "Failed to initialize Unity graphics" in Unity3D

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

Hi when I create new project in unity it's showing "**Failed to create unity graphics**" error.

Graphics driver is already installed in my machine.

How can i resolve this issue?
Please help me.

[image]

[image]

Comment: A quick search brought up [this](https://support.unity3d.com/hc/en-us/articles/206560153-I-cannot-open-the-Unity-Editor-in-Windows-due-to-a-failure-initializing-unity-graphics-). Have you got Direct3D acceleration enabled?

Comment: Yes checked directx features it's not available

Comment: How to enable directx features?

Comment: DirectX isn't available? What hardware are you trying to run it on?

Comment: windows 7 machine

Comment: Do you have admin access to run things like `dxdiag`?

Comment: NO i don't have i logged in as a user

Comment: You're missing drivers like `nvd3dum.dll` - how did you install windows?

Comment: I haven't installed anything now it's already installed in my machine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135343/discussion-between-luke-briggs-and-user-android).

Comment: How can i install nvd3dum.dll? if i installed that driver it will works fine?

Comment: Click on the chat link above :)

Comment: @yazhini, If you figure out a solution to this problem, it would be helpful to post it as an answer for people in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution which I figured out was,we need to update the Graphics card then it will work fine.